# Replacing rows based on conditions on the same column

Tags: r, dplyr, replace

I am trying to replace the rows based on the conditions of the previous rows. Please note the column is character not numbers.

| Power | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1257 | Compressor |
| 1689 | Compressor |
| 897 | Compressor |
| 753 | Compressor |
| 514 | Compressor |
| 151 | Compressor |
| 77 | FanOnly |
| 49 | FanOnly |
| 16 | Controls |
| 15 | Controls |
| 77 | FanOnly |
| 67 | FanOnly |
| 90 | FanOnly |
| 111 | FanOnly |

In the above data frame, I would like to replace all the rows with the Status of 'FanOnly' with 'Compressor', if the previous row is 'Compressor'. There are several occasions when the last row is not 'Compressor'; for those occasions, I do not want to replace 'FanOnly' with 'Compressor. Please note 'Power' is numeric and 'Status' is a character.

The following is the desired data frame,

| Power | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1257 | Compressor |
| 1689 | Compressor |
| 897 | Compressor |
| 753 | Compressor |
| 514 | Compressor |
| 151 | Compressor |
| 77 | Compressor |
| 49 | Compressor |
| 16 | Controls |
| 15 | Controls |
| 77 | FanOnly |
| 67 | FanOnly |
| 90 | FanOnly |
| 111 | FanOnly |

The replacement could be made considering the 'Status' column alone or both the 'Power' & 'Status' columns.

Many thanks for the help.

I tried lag, lead and other examples from the forum, but I am finding difficulty in obtaining the desired output.

Comment: But, in the desired outcome you are replacing the row with `49` although there the previous row does not have `Compressor`.

Comment: @novica, I edited my question now. I want to replace all the rows with 'FanOnly' to 'Compressor' if my said condition is met. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in base R, we can do it with a loop:

```r
dt$Status_change <- dt$Status

for(i in 2:nrow(dt))
  dt$Status_change[i] <- ifelse(dt$Status_change[i] == "FanOnly" && dt$Status_change[i - 1] == "Compressor",
                         "Compressor", 
                         dt$Status_change[i])

dt
#>    Compressor_Power     Status Status_change
#> 1              1257 Compressor    Compressor
#> 2              1689 Compressor    Compressor
#> 3               897 Compressor    Compressor
#> 4               753 Compressor    Compressor
#> 5               514 Compressor    Compressor
#> 6               151 Compressor    Compressor
#> 7                77    FanOnly    Compressor
#> 8                49    FanOnly    Compressor
#> 9                16   Controls      Controls
#> 10               15   Controls      Controls
#> 11               77    FanOnly       FanOnly
#> 12               67    FanOnly       FanOnly
#> 13               90    FanOnly       FanOnly
#> 14              111    FanOnly       FanOnly
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks, @M Aurélio. Thanks for teaching me the way. Appreciate it